# Is MongoDb lock more than 100% normal?

Tags: java, performance, mongodb, mongo-java

Hi I'm trying to upsert a document on a collection of ~7 million documents. Here's the record from my profile

```
{
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "productService.products20140117",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : "77004704"
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$set" : {
            "some long document"
        }
    },
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "idhack" : true,
    "nupdated" : 1,
    "fastmodinsert" : true,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(203)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(0),
            "w" : NumberLong(3)
        }
    },
    "millis" : 0,
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-01-17T10:44:26.868Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

And this is what I get from `mongostat`

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults                locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  11.4g  13.8g  2.02g      1    productService:200.2%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     3k     3   17:07:44 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  11.4g  13.8g  2.02g      0    productService:199.8%          0       0|0     0|1    62b     3k     3   17:07:45 
    *0     *0      1     *0       0     2|0       0  11.4g  13.8g  2.02g      0    productService:294.0%          0       0|0     0|1   335b     3k     3   17:07:46 
    *0     *0     *0     *0       0     1|0       0  11.4g  13.8g  2.02g      0     productService:11.9%          0       0|0     0|1    62b
```

Is this normal, I think it's not. But how do I lower the lock%. Or is my collection too large? I'm doing this on my Macbook Air, 8GB. If this could be a problem how do I fix high percentage of lock?

I'm using Java Driver 2.1.11 and MongoDb 2.4

Comment: Did you check [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) on `mongostat`?  They do describe the potential for >100% with `locked db`.

Comment: Yeah, but what caused that. I was running around 50% and then it shot up.